# Pecl install sqlsrv returns No releases available for package

Tags: php, php-7, pecl, sqlsrv

While installing sqlsrv module for PHP7 i'm getting following error -

> No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/sqlsrv

Command used

```
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: what command are you running?

Comment: @SamuelCook updated my question -Sorry about that.

Answer (score 6):

Same problem here... Solved installing modules as root this way (Ubuntu 16.04):

```
    wget http://pecl.php.net/get/sqlsrv-4.3.0.tgz
    pear install sqlsrv-4.3.0.tgz

    wget http://pecl.php.net/get/pdo_sqlsrv-4.3.0.tgz
    pear install pdo_sqlsrv-4.3.0.tgz
```

You can check latests available versions here: http://pecl.php.net/package-search.php?pkg_name=sqlsrv&bool=AND&submit=Search

And check if php modules are enabled after installation:

```
    php -m | grep sqlsrv
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to install a certain version that you know exists:

```
$ pecl install sqlsrv-4.3.0
```

Also try to clear the cache:

```
$ pear clear-cache
```

Comment: No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/sqlsrv"
install failed

Comment: clearing the cache worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For corporate proxy users, you might just need to tell pear to use your proxy.

```
pear config-set http_proxy http://proxy.example.com:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes [pecl.php.net](https://pecl.php.net) is not available or down. In this case `pecl install` may show "no releases available".

Just for information.

Answer (score 0):

The installation of pecl/sqlsrv requires PHP version >= 7.2.0. sqlsrv extension for PHP 7.1 was removed from pecl repository.

Precompiled binaries for older sqlsrv which support PHP 7.1 can be found at https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.6.1.

Precompiled binaries for older sqlsrv which support PHP 7.0 can be found at https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.3.0

It is also possible to use an older system version of PHP. For example, in order to connect to MSSQL on CentOS 7 with system PHP version 5.4, the following command needed to be executed:

```bash
yum install epel-release
yum install php-mssql
```

Instructions for installing Microsoft driver for SQL Server Linux can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=alpine18-install%2Calpine17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline

Instructions for PLESK users: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/12377482190999--How-to-install-the-sqlsrv-extension-for-the-Plesk-PHP-handlers-