# How to connect to MSSQL Server with PHP from Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu-18.04

I want to establish a MSSQL Connection from Ubunutu 18.04. It was quite hard to get this set up, but know it works so far that I can use sql_srv class or pdo class.
But when I want to connect, the connection fails with error

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found [message] => [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found ) ).
```

How can I resolve this issue and what does this error mean? 
I've installed ODBC 17.

```
 odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

And the nano /etc/odbcinst.ini shows:

> [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17
>   for SQL Server
>   Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.5.so.1.1
>   UsageCount=1

What should I do to connect with MSSQL Server 2014 from ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Where is your code? Why are you using odbc?

Comment: dear user, what else can I use? I try to connect this two ways: sqlsrv_connect and with new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servername,$port;Database=$database;ConnectionPooling=0", $username, $password);

both failed

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
via this three pages I could install the correct Driver Version:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu17

[Pecl install sqlsrv returns No releases available for package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220954/pecl-install-sqlsrv-returns-no-releases-available-for-package)

Download drivers from http://pecl.php.net/package/sqlsrv/5.8.0

```
sudo bash -c "echo extension=sqlsrv.so > /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini"
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/sqlsrv.ini
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/sqlsrv.ini
sudo bash -c "echo extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so > /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini"
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/pdo_sqlsrv.ini


sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install PECL
2. Follow steps mentioned on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15
3. Restart Apache
4. Use below PHP script to test the connection

> ```
> //format: serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433)
> $serverName = "localhost";
>
> $connectionInfo = array("Database" => "dbName", "UID" => "myUserName", "PWD" => "myPassword");
> $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
>
> if ($conn) {
>     echo "Got a connection!<br />";
> } else {
>     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
>     die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Use [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for Microsoft SQL Server](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql). You will find detailed installation instructions there.

Comment: Hello, this does not work for me. The last option for go live was to switch to a Windowsserver...

Comment: because I can not get connection, cause my .so file is not find in php. There is no _pdo tag for that in phpinfo();

Comment: Make sure you install correct PHP versions of the extensions. The detailed instructions can be found at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/ubuntu/step/2.html. The drivers work itself work well with Ubuntu.